# Chrome WebSocket - onopen is not a function

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I have a really simple websocket test on chrome, but it seems to be failing miserably:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8002/', 'a')

 ws.onopen(function() {
     console.log("ok")
 })
```

It tells me: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onopen' of object #<WebSocket> is not a function`. I would assume that onopen should exist as a method whether or not there is a websocket server actually running, but I do have one running on that port.

I'm using chrome 32.0.1700. I see that all of the callback methods (onopen, onmessage, etc) are all null. What's going on here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The function is not correctly assigned to the onopen event. Do it like this instead:

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8002/', 'a')

ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log("ok")
};
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

Comment: That gives me no information, and also tutorials point seems to indicate I'm doing things correctly. Could you indicate what I'm missing by looking at tutorialspoint?

Comment: To clarify for anyone else: `ws.onopen` is initially undefined, so you need to assign a function to the property. This is different from using `ws.addEventListener('open', fn)`